# Laravel: Use sync or updateOrCreate for updating parent table and child table?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, one-to-many, laravel-relations

I have a parent table like this:

**clubs**

| id | name | budget |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Arsenal | 90 |
| 2 | Chelsea | 150 |
| 3 | Man City | 135 |
| 4 | Man Utd | 140 |
| 5 | Tottenham | 87 |

And a child table like this

**players**

| id | club_id | name | position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | Grealish | LM |
| 2 | 3 | Sterling | LW |
| 3 | 3 | Haaland | ST |
| 4 | 1 | Dybala | ST |
| 5 | 1 | Casemiro | DM |
| 6 | 4 | Fred | DM |
| 7 | 2 | Mbappe | ST |
| 8 | 2 | Hazard | LW |
| 9 | 4 | Varane | DM |

The club_id is the foreign key that refer to the clubs table id column

**Club Model**

```
public function players()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Player', 'club_id', 'id');
}
```

**Player Model**

```
public function club()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Club', 'club_id', 'id');
}
```

I have an array input and logic to create a club and player like this:

```
// the array create input will contain the club and all the players that is related to the club
$createInput = array(
  'title' => 'Liverpool',
  'budget' => '70'
  'players' => [
      [ 
         'name' => 'Handerson',
         'Position' => 'CM'
      ],
      [ 
         'name' => 'Milner',
         'Position' => 'LW'
      ]
   ]
);

$club = new Club;
$club->name = $createInput['name];
$club->budget = $createInput['name];
$club->save();
foreach($createInput['players'] as $playerInput){
  $player = new Player;
  $player->name = $playerInput['name'];
  $player->position = $playerInput['position'];
  $player->save();
}]
```

and I have an array input and logic to update club and player like this:

```
// the array update input will contain the club and all the players that are related to the club

$updateInput = array(
  'id'.  => 1,
  'budget' => '50',
  'players' => [
      [ 
         'id' => '4',
         'name' => 'Dybala',
         'Position' => 'ST'
      ],
      [ 
         'name' => 'Sane',
         'Position' => 'LW'
      ],
      [ 
         'name' => 'De Ligt',
         'Position' => 'DF'
      ]
   ]
);

$club = Club::find($updateInput['id']);
if(isset($updateInput['name'])) $club->name = $updateInput['name'];
if(isset($updateInput['budget'])) $club->budget = $updateInput['budget'];
$club->save();

$existingIds = [];
foreach($updateInput['players'] as $playerInput){
  if(isset($playerInput['id'])) $player = Player::find($playerInput['id']);
  else $player = new Player;
  if(isset($updateInput['name'])) $player->name = $playerInput['name'];
  if(isset($updateInput['position'])) $player->name = $playerInput['position'];
  $player->save();
  $existingIds[] = $player->id;
}

//if the player id is not in the input data then delete it 

DB::table('players')->whereNotIn('id', $existingIds)->where('club_id', $club->id)->delete();
```

I'm planning to simplify my code by using the sync and createorupdate method, but i'm not sure which one is more suitable for inserting/updating/deleting related players data which are connected to the clubs table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a defined relationship then why not used that:

When you are **creating** a new records:

```
$club = new Club;
$club->name = $createInput['name];
$club->budget = $createInput['name];
$club->save();

// club_id automatic attach with players
$club->players()->createMany( $createInput['players'] );
```

While **updating** records with relationship:

```
$club = Club::find($updateInput['id']);
if(isset($updateInput['name'])) $club->name = $updateInput['name'];
if(isset($updateInput['budget'])) $club->budget = $updateInput['budget'];
$club->save();

foreach($updateInput['players'] as $playerInput){
    $playerData = $club->players()->updateOrCreate(
        ['id' => $playerInput['id']],
        ['name' => $playerInput['name'], 'position' => $playerInput['position']]
    );
}
```

When you needed **deleting** records with parent relationship:

```
$club = Club::find( $id_of_club );
$club->players()->delete();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is the updateOrCreate will return a player model, because i need to retrieve the id to delete the player that does not exist in input ?

Comment: @Padawan Offcourse into the loop where create or update method call, You can assign data into the variable and get id as well

Comment: is there a way we can specifically filter which players need to delete using player id for example `$club->players()->->whereNotIn('id', $existingIds)->delete();`

Comment: @Padawan Yes but you need to create a logic that collects ids before `updateOrCreate` actions and deleted all of the players without `updateInput` id